# Paying via Admob

Tags: admob, payment

I make apps and wish to divide the income with the distributor on a %.

However, if I wire the money home, I instantly have to pay taxes and only after could I pay their share - but that share is for the total revenue, not my taxed so I would be left with less and I wish to get around that.

Is there a way to ask admob to automatically distribute the income between two accounts for projects, or a way to send money directly from my admob acc to theirs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: Okay and it's fair, but I have no means to ask elsewhere. Could you suggest another forum for this?